# Cannot connect to a database in PLSQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to connect to the database with PLSQL Developer. But the application shows that the path to my TNS file is located in another Windows Account that i do not have the access to (corporate PC). Furthermore, i do not have the same directory on my Windows account. What can I do?[info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j9go.png) [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOjJd.png)

I tried changing the TNS Path with through CMD, but when new PLSQL opens, it still doesnt have the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- in any folder you have access to (or create a new one, e.g. `Documents\My_Oracle`) create a new `TNSNAMES.ORA` file
- edit **environment variables** for your account (note that this is different from editing **system** environment variables! You might not have privileges to do that, regarding that this is a corporate PC)
- create a **new** variable named `TNS_ADMIN`

  - its value should be path to folder we discussed earlier, the one that contains your copy of the `TNSNAMES.ORA` file
  - on my PC, it points to `C:\Users\littlefoot\Documents\My_Oracle` folder

Once you're done, **all** tools you'd want to use to access Oracle databases listed in `TNSNAMES.ORA` file should be able to establish connection. These tools can be SQL*Plus, Oracle SQL Developer, TOAD, your **PL/SQL Developer**, Oracle Forms, ... *everything*.

To illustrate it:

[image]

---

**[EDIT]**

About ORA-12154: error is related to client computer (i.e. your own PC). You (i.e. the *client*) are trying to connect to a database, but name you provided can't be resolved to any database.

That's similar to you - trying to call someone on the phone - but you can't find their name in a phonebook.

The most frequent cause is the fact that database alias can't be found in `TNSNAMES.ORA` file.

`SQLNET.ORA` file might also have its role; do you have that file? What is its contents? Put it into the same folder where `TNSNAMES.ORA` file is!

For example, this is my `SQLNET.ORA` file:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)    
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH = (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

For more info, have a look at what Ed Stevens (he's a DBA; I'm not) says about [troubleshooting ORA-12154](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/troubleshooting-ora-12154/).

Comment: I followed your steps and now the TNS File path is correct, and all the servers are listed in Names TNS tab, but I still cannot connect to the DB I want. It gives the same TNS Error even though TNS list contains that DB. Do you happen to know why it can happen?

Comment: Can it be because the DLLs and OraClient11g_home2 still have path to another account's files?